# Drawing virtual dotted line using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, vector, pyqgis-3, qgsrubberband

I am developing a plugin in QGIS 3.14 to customize editing. I am drawing a line by clicking on map canvas. It is showing points with mouse click and creating a line with right click. I want to trace mouse by showing dotted line while generating points. Just like existing 'Add Line Feature' function of 'Toggle Editing' in QGIS. Following is the code which I am using now.

```py
class StraightLine(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    points = []

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        # call the parent constructor
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, canvas)
        # store the passed canvas
        self.canvas = canvas

        # flag to know whether the tool is performing a drawing operation 
        self.isDrawing = False
        self.dlg = CurveToolDialog()
        # create and setup the rubber band to display the line
        self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(iface.mapCanvas(), QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)  
        self.rubberBand.setColor(Qt.red)
        self.rubberBand.setWidth(1)
        self.dlg.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus) 

    def clear(self):
        self.rubberBand.reset(False)    # False = not a polygon = a line

    def delete(self):
        self.canvas.scene().removeItem(self.rubberBand)
    
    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        # which the mouse button?
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # left click
            # if it's the first left click, clear the rubberband 
            if not self.isDrawing:
                self.clear()
                self.points = []
            # we are drawing now
            self.isDrawing = True
            point = self.toMapCoordinates(e.pos())
            # add a new point to the rubber band
            self.rubberBand.addPoint(point, True)    # True = display updates on the canvas
            self.points.append(QgsPoint(point))
            polyline = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(self.points)
            feat = QgsFeature()
            feat.setGeometry(polyline)            
            self.rubberBand.setToGeometry(polyline)
            self.rubberBand.movePoint(point)
            self.rubberBand.show()
            # and finally show the rubber band
            self.rubberBand.show()
            
        if e.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            
            # right click, stop drawing
            self.isDrawing = False
            # emit a signal
            polyline = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(self.points)
            feat = QgsFeature()
            feat.setGeometry(polyline)            
            self.rubberBand.setToGeometry(polyline)
            self.rubberBand.show()  
            layer = iface.activeLayer()
            f = layer.getFeature(0)
            prov1 = layer.dataProvider()
            layer.startEditing()
            prov1.addFeatures([feat])
            feat.setAttributes(f.attributes())
            layer.commitChanges()
            layer.updateExtents()
            iface.mapCanvas().refresh()  
            self.dlg.open()
           
    def geometry(self):
        return self.rubberBand.asGeometry()
```

I tried adding following function which uses painter, but it doesn't make any change in working of the tool.

```py
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.last:
        self.painter.drawLine(self.last, event.pos())
        self.last = event.pos()
        self.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting temporary rubber band different from actual rubber band helped.line style of temporary one was kept as dotted.Also, including `canvasMoveEvent` to draw temporary rubber band.

```py
def canvasMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.tempRubberBand != None and self.capturing:
        mapPt,layerPt = self.transformCoordinates(event.pos())
        self.tempRubberBand.movePoint(mapPt)

def startCapturing(self):
    color = QColor("red")
    color.setAlphaF(0.78)
    self.rubberBand = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas,QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)
    self.rubberBand.setWidth(2)
    self.rubberBand.setColor(color)
    self.rubberBand.show()
    self.tempRubberBand = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas,QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)
    self.tempRubberBand.setWidth(2)
    self.tempRubberBand.setColor(color)
    self.tempRubberBand.setLineStyle(Qt.DotLine)
    self.tempRubberBand.show()
    self.capturing = True
```